# React Native: dynamic image require in component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to show a randomly generated image  in my Image component, however I'm getting the following error:

```
invalid call at line 58:require(getRandomImage())
```

My component:

```
const [ randomImages, setRandomImages ] = useState([
        //require('../assets/images/aranda.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/bilmore.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/cachalote.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/lola.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/meson.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/paloma.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/picasso.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/pimpi.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/tintero.jpg'),
        require('@assets/images/tropicana.jpg'),
    ]);

const getRandomImage = () =>
    {
        return randomImages[rand(0,9)];
    };

    const rand = (min, max) => 
    {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
    }


<Image style={{ width:'100%', height:200,}}  resizeMode="cover" source={require(getRandomImage())}/>
```

Comment: remove the `require` in the `image` source, leave it like this: `source={getRandomImage()}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove `'@'` in `randomImages` array,you do not need to use `../` or `@`, It must be like the following :

```
const [ randomImages, setRandomImages ] = useState([
  //require('assets/images/aranda.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/bilmore.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/cachalote.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/lola.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/meson.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/paloma.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/picasso.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/pimpi.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/tintero.jpg'),
  require('assets/images/tropicana.jpg'),
]);
```

and use it as below :

```
  <Image  style={{ width:'100%', height:200,}}  resizeMode="cover" source={getRandomImage()} height="200" />
```